# Windows Mobile Device Center error

Tags: sync, windows-10, windows-phone, activesync, windows-mobile-6

I have an old smartphone. A HTC HD2 running Windows Mobile 6.5

Till Windows 7, I had no problems to synchronize my contacts, Calendar and Task with my pc via Windows Mobile Device Center.

Now, I upgraded my PC to Windows 10 and replaced the Windows Mobile Device Center with the new version.

Since, I cannot synchronize any more.
Each time I get the message 'Exchange Activesync encountered an error'.
There is no error number, no suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sync center will provide the synchronization required.  You will need to reconfigure the sync. Follow these steps:

1. Windows key + X > Control Panel > Sync Center
2. Select Sync step
3. Connect your device via USB

Nice pic of Windows Mobile 6.5 devices. I still own a HTC HD2 and its still my favorite Windows Mobile 6.5 device :)

Comment: my device is already connected but i cannot see it :(